# Reusing Bitmap in Android

Tags: android, performance, bitmap

I have to draw a lot of objects on the game screen made of same Bitmap. So, I need to find a good way to reuse bitmap. I have a class where Bitmap is a field, and every object on the screen is an instance of this class (or its subclass). How can the best performance be achieved in this case?

Thanks for advices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make the bitmap field static then only one instance exists. But in this case you need to manage drawing access to this object.

Answer (score 2):

How about having a `BitmapCache` class which would be responsible for storing/caching/retrieving all the `Bitmap` objects.